# How to run python file repeatedly every day in GCP(google cloud platform)?

Tags: database, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, cron-task

I have written python code to move data from firestore to Bigquery. 
How can I run this code at a specified time every day?
Please help beginner

Comment: Have you looked into Cloud Scheduler calling a Cloud Functions or Cloud Run service endpoint? There is also App Engine, Firebase and Compute Engine.

Answer (score 2):

The most economical way would be to use [Google Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler). It can initiate a job that runs on a schedule, similar to corn. Then via Pub/Sub it can invoke Google Cloud Function with your code.

Here is the tutorial, describing exactly that: https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/tut-pub-sub Just use Python, instead of JavaScript for runtime.